# Assigning values to an array (Bash script error)

Tags: arrays, bash

I have been told that you can assign values to an array and make it at the simultaneously in bash script using this code:

`arrayName[0]=1`

However this does not work for me and keeps throwing up this error:

`array[0]=1: not found`

Can someone please point out the error of my ways

Comment: I'm not having any problem with it in Cygwin's bash. Can you provide more context around the line with the error?

Comment: I have no problem with this under my msysgit bash shell.  Can you make sure you're running bash(ha ha, jk), are you sure your spacing is exactly as we see it here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you sure you're doing exactly `array[0]=1`? Having an extra space on any hand of the expression would break it.

Comment: `/bin/sh` may not be bash in your system. Try again with `#!/bin/bash`, and post your code using code tags in the actual question for a better chance to detect formatting errors.